# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger.internal.Preconditions android dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am switching between two project using build flavor. I am using dagger2 and one project working fine but when switching another project and trying to run it showing below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger.internal.Preconditions
at common.di.DaggerAppComponent$Builder.appModule(DaggerAppComponent.java:35)
```

Here is my gradle dependency:

```
// Dependency Injection
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

The issue is mainly when adding appModule in AppComponent.

```
private AppComponent createAppComponent() {

    return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this)) //Problem is here
            .networkModule(new NetworkModule())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I have found the root cause. Its basically API level issue.
For android **API level below 21** you need to add following dependency in build gradle file. Also change the Application class to MultiDexApplication like below:

In app build.gradle file:

```
Implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

In you BaseApplication change Application class to `MultiDexApplication`:

```
public class BaseApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```